# registering services in ConfigureServices method is giving error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to register one services in `ConfigureServices` method like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<FeatureToggle>(x => new FeatureToggle{ 
            DeveloperException = configuration.GetValue<bool>("FeatureToggles:DeveloperExceptions")
        });

        services.AddMvc();            
    }
```

But while debugging I am getting error as given in the image below

[image]

The error was generated after adding line

`services.AddMvc();`

Comment: Which version of asp.net core ?

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh: I am using `asp.netcore 2.1`